# Which application send/receive data through network?

Tags: networking

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Shortly after system boot, before I start any application, I open the System Monitor and in Network History graph see something like that:

[image: Network History from System Monitor]

How do I find out which application or process is responsible for this traffic?

**UPD:**

I tried `nethogs`, but surprisingly it does not detect all the activity in question. For example:

[image: Network History from System Monitor 2]

Before the event which is circled in green `nethogs` saw just nothing (`nethogs` in 'total' mode):

```
NetHogs version 0.8.5-2build1

    PID USER     PROGRAM                            DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
      ? root     unknown TCP                                    0.000       0.000 KB

  TOTAL                                                         0.000       0.000 KB
```

It did saw the event circled in green:

```
NetHogs version 0.8.5-2build1

    PID USER     PROGRAM                            DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
    929 root     /usr/sbin/NetworkManager           wlp3s0      0.415       0.475 KB
      ? root     unknown TCP                                    0.000       0.000 KB

  TOTAL                                                         0.415       0.475 KB
```

but several seconds later did not notice the event circled in orange - the above readings did not change. And all the narrow peaks go unnoticed.

Comment: You could try to set up a firewall with logging and read logs. Don't know exactly how to do it in details, but you could try https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html

Comment: At first the ufw looked a bit complicated, so I started with simpler tool, but now I am going to give it a try, thank you. It would be nice if someone gives more specific suggestion about how to use the ufw in my task.